# How to pass UIImage to phonegap to be viewed in an Image control?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am doing an image manipulation application in IOS. I have done the basic image conversion tasks in an objective-c native application. now I need to embed this with a phonegap plugin application. let's say I have a method to get an image (Image url) from the phonegap side to my native plugin. i convert the image to grayscale and return it as UIImage at the moment. I want to know how it should be converted and passed in a way that it can be send to phonegap side and view in an Image control.

can someone please give me an idea on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        -(NSString *)UIImageToBaseSixtyFour:(UIImage *)sourceImage
    {
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(sourceImage, 1.0); 

        NSString *base64 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(sourceImage, 0.95) base64EncodedString]];

        return base64;

    }
```

that's my code. it works fine. I just tried to  print base64 to NSLog and it gives me the output.

in addition to this I needed to get the NSdata+Base64.h and NSdata+Base64.m files from git hub github.com/l4u/NSData-Base64  and add to my project and imported the "NSData+Base64.h" file. It works fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert your image to base64 and send the image as a string your plugin successCallback.

The following is a basic implementation of what you can do

```
// EDPicturePlugin.h
@interface EDPicturePlugin : CDVPlugin <EDCameraControllerDelegate>
- (void)takePicture:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
@end

// EDPicturePlugin.m
@interface EDPicturePlugin()

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *callbackID;    

@end

@implementation EDPicturePlugin

- (void)takePicture:(CDVInvokeUrlCommand*)command
{
   self.callbackID = command.callbackID;
   EDCameraController *cameraController = [[EDCameraController alloc] init]
   cameraController.delegate = self;
   [self.viewController presentViewController:cameraController];
   [cameraController release];
}

// EDCameraControllerDelegate
- (void)cameraController:(EDCameraController*)controller 
        didFinishTakingImageWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{
   UIImage *image = info[@"image"];
   NSString *base64 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:image/jpeg;base64",[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.95) base64EncodedString];
   CDVPluginResult *result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK
                                               messageAsString:base64];
   [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:self.callbackID];
   [callbackID release];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. can someone provide me some code sample on that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the sample code. I have one more question related to this. If the image is converted to base64 and passed as as a string, is it possible for me to view it in an Image control in the phonegap side. I mean in my index.html page

Comment: yes sure : <div id="div_id"  style="background-image: url(<here the base64>) >

Comment: NSString *base64 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:image/jpeg;base64",[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.95) base64EncodedString]; line of code gives me an error saying there's no NSData interface declaring the selector base64EncodedString. can someone help me with that.

Comment: OK, I added the NSdata+Base64.h and NSdata+Base64.m files from git hub   http://github.com/l4u/NSData-Base64/ imported the "NSData+Base64.h" file. I'm not getting errors now.          NSString *base64 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:image/jpeg;base64",[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.95) base64EncodedString];  line does not return such value. to  do so, use @"%@" instead of @"data:image/jpeg;base64"